# .htaccess exclude directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble excluding a few of my directories from a rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(cultivsearchenginesitemap|RSS)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.niklashjelm.se/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to exclude the directories on the third line but they keep getting the trailing slash, have tried placing it before and after the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: The regex in the second `RewriteCond` could just be written `/$`, no need to match the rest

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you don't want the redirect to `www.niklashjelm.se` to occur for these two directories then line 3 should be the cond (or some tweak to this):

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(cultivsearchenginesitemap|RSS)/?
```

Comment: Thanks, found another way around it.